# Using Eclipse to test intents in android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I have recently created an Android application that allows users to add shopping items and lists to a database and need to test its functionality. I have found information on testing whether certain TextViews contain the correct strings etc but that's about it.

I need to have a test project that actually adds food items and tests whether that was successful, I was thinking maybe:

- Moving to the desired Activity
- Filling out and submitting the form to add a shopping item
- Move to the Activity containing all food items and their details
- Check the item was added correctly

Is this possible to do using an Android test project in Eclipse? If not, are there any other useful tools available for this kind of testing?

Comment: What you are describing is not unit testing (referring to your tag). This is more of functional testing. And yes there are some functional testing tools for testing android (not used them though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, see android.testing.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<>. You can set up an Intent to be given to the activity under test using setActivityIntent(), then do getActivity() to start the activity under test. There are tutorials in the Developers Guide for learning how to use ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be much documentation for setActivityIntent(), and my guess is that it doesn't test intent filtering.

I think you should do it as unit tests. First ensure that your source Activity is issuing the correct intents by writing a test destination that simply logs all the incoming Intent data.
Then write unit tests for the destination, based on setActivityIntent(). You can also use
Robotium or MonkeyRunner (part of Android).

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful. I have seen most of the tools you have mentioned but like you said, it is hard to find any documentation. I have resorted to writing my own test cases manually and agree with you on testing the intents. It seems easier that way.

Answer (score 2):

You cam use `adb shell am` to open a activity or send broadcast.
For example. You want to open a activity, the component of it is "com.test/.MainActivity". then you just need to type "adb shell -n com.test/.MainActivity".

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to test it all manually. I was wondering if it was possible to automate a run through of adding and removing items etc, utilising all functionality of the application?

Comment: Then you can check. Monkeyrunner which is written in Python to automatic test Android. App.  You can find how use it on android.developer website.

Comment: Oh right thanks, if I had the time that seems perfect so I have upvoted your answer, however I have decided on writing a few of my own methods to test the main part of my application, using some information given by Joe Malin (below)

Answer (score 2):

I have asked around and a friend of mine told me a list of tools you can use to functionally test android application.

Freeware:

- [FoneMonkey](http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey)
- [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/)

Commercial products:

- [SeeTest](http://experitest.com/android-automation-now-available-with-seetest/)
- [uTest](http://www.utest.com/mobile-app-testing)
- [Perfecto Mobile](http://www.perfectomobile.com/)
- [Test Center Enterprise Automation](http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/mobile-application-testing-automation.html) (Keynote Device Anywhere)

He recommended FoneMonkey as good enough tool for functional testing. I don't think you can implement functional tests for Android Application using only Android library testing tools without any third party extensions.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to test your database, you can open `File Explorer` of ADT, save your database to other place and open by other database reader. (such as: `SQLite Database Browser`)

Comment: Oh right thanks! That makes testing the database much easier =)